# Filter an array using value from another array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to filter `Schedules[ ]` Array using `Dates[ ] Array` where `"date_id" == "schedule_date_id"`.

I need only those elements where `date_id` matches `schedule_date_id` and then reload the table. I need to show Schedules according to dates.

What is the Swift code for this?

Below is the JSON I have:

```
{
dates =     (
            {
        "date_date" = "2017-11-04";
        "date_id" = 4;
        "date_image" = "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/schedule-days/day_1.png";
        "date_title" = "Day 1";
    },
            {
        "date_date" = "2017-11-05";
        "date_id" = 5;
        "date_image" = "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/schedule-days/day_2.png";
        "date_title" = "Day 2";
    }
);
schedules =     (
            {
        "schedule_date" = "2017-11-04";
        "schedule_date_id" = 4;
        "schedule_description" = "Schedule 7";
        "schedule_end_time" = "14:00:00";
        "schedule_id" = 7;
        "schedule_image" = "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/schedules/day_1.png";
        "schedule_location" = Mumbai;
        "schedule_start_time" = "11:00:00";
    },
            {
        "schedule_date" = "2017-11-04";
        "schedule_date_id" = 4;
        "schedule_description" = "Schedule 8";
        "schedule_end_time" = "14:00:00";
        "schedule_id" = 8;
        "schedule_image" = "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/schedules/day_1.png";
        "schedule_location" = Mumbai;
        "schedule_start_time" = "11:00:00";
    },
            {
        "schedule_date" = "2017-11-04";
        "schedule_date_id" = 4;
        "schedule_description" = "Schedule 9";
        "schedule_end_time" = "14:00:00";
        "schedule_id" = 9;
        "schedule_image" = "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/schedules/day_1.png";
        "schedule_location" = Mumbai;
        "schedule_start_time" = "11:00:00";
    },
            {
        "schedule_date" = "2017-11-05";
        "schedule_date_id" = 5;
        "schedule_description" = "Schedule 10";
        "schedule_end_time" = "14:00:00";
        "schedule_id" = 10;
        "schedule_image" = "https://project-isdental-cammy92.c9users.io/api/images/schedules/day_2.png";
        "schedule_location" = Mumbai;
        "schedule_start_time" = "11:00:00";
    }
);
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're looking to do.  Are you trying to do a join?

Comment: @DavidBerry I need elements from Schedule [ ] where "schedule_id" from Schedule [ ] should match "date_id" in Dates[ ]

Comment: I think you want to match `date_id` with `schedule_date_id ` not `schedule_id`, right ?

Comment: @RobertD.Mogos yeah, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter `schedules` array using `date_id` from datesArray

```
let dateId = 4
let filteredSchedules = schedules.filter { schedule in
    dates.contains(where: { dateId as! Int == schedule["schedule_id"] as! Int }
)}
print(filteredSchedules)
```

To assign dates to collectionView cell

```
cell.titleLabel.text = datesArray[indexPath.row]["datesArray"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use like this:

**Swift 4**

```
let filteredSchedules = schedules.filter { schedule in
    dates.contains(where: { $0["date_id"] as! Int == schedule["schedule_id"] as! Int }
)}
print(filteredSchedules)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let filteredSchedules = schedules.filter { schedule in
    dates.contains({ $0["date_id"] as! Int == schedule["schedule_id"] as! Int })
}
print(filteredSchedules)
```

Comment: showing this error : Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: showing  error at $0 : Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

Comment: Is your `schedules` or `dates` array optional?

Comment: DateArray = EventSchedule["dates"]  as! NSArray I've declared Dates array as this

Comment: Use like this : datesArray = EventSchedule["dates"] as! [String: Any]

Comment: I've declared DatesArray like this :  var DateArray : NSArray  = [] before viewDidLoad() and then DateArray = EventSchedule["dates"] as! NSArray inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156881/discussion-between-vini-app-and-shikha-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
let newArray  = schedulesArray.filter { (schedulesDic) -> Bool in
            return datesArray.contains(where: { (datesDic) -> Bool in
                if schedulesDic["schedule_id"] as! Int == datesDic["date_id"] as! Int{
                    return true
                }
                else {
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
print(newArray)
```

Or short form of above code

```
let newArray  = schedulesArray.filter { (schedulesDic) -> Bool in
            datesArray.contains(where: { $0["date_id"] as! Int == schedulesDic["schedule_id"] as! Int })
        }
print(newArray)
```

Comment: showing  error at $0 : Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type